# Dask apply throwing error using right meta

Tags: python, pandas, dask

I'm starting using dask, but ran into some error that makes no sense to me.

I'm trying to rum the following code:

```
import dask.dataframe as dd

testpd = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "SKU_ID": {0: 1, 1: 1, 2: 1, 3: 1, 4: 1, 5: 2, 6: 2},
        "STR_ID": {0: 1, 1: 1, 2: 1, 3: 1, 4: 1, 5: 64, 6: 64},
        "DATE": {
            0: Timestamp("2018-01-01 00:00:00"),
            1: Timestamp("2018-01-02 00:00:00"),
            2: Timestamp("2018-01-03 00:00:00"),
            3: Timestamp("2018-01-04 00:00:00"),
            4: Timestamp("2018-01-05 00:00:00"),
            5: Timestamp("2020-02-22 00:00:00"),
            6: Timestamp("2020-02-23 00:00:00"),
        },
        "ORD_UNITS": {0: 0, 1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 0, 4: 0, 5: 0, 6: 0},
    }
)

testdd = dd.from_pandas(testpd, npartitions=2,)

def func(x):
    return pd.Series(x["DATE"] == x["DATE"].min(), name="result")
```

with pandas, works perfectly: `testpd.groupby(["SKU_ID", "STR_ID"]).apply(func)`

But with dask I got:

```
testdd.groupby(["SKU_ID", "STR_ID"]).apply(
    func, meta=pd.Series([], dtype=bool, name="result")
).compute()
```

`AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'columns'`

Comment: I recommend raising an issue, with a complete traceback, at https://github.com/dask/dask/issues/new